# log4net programmatically set appender

Tags: log4net

I want to have log4net write to one file for debug messages and another for all other messages and I want to set this all up programatically. I can see how to specify the lower limit of an appender but no the upper limit (ie prevent the debug appender from writing messages above debug  level).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Never tried it, but I suspect it is something like `appender.AddFilter(new log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter() { LevelMin = Level.Info , LevelMax = Level.Error  }  );`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
    Hierarchy hierarchy = 
        (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

    hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(appender);
```

where appender is of type IAppender